# how can you index a 9 speed 11-46 tooth cassette if the gears arent equally apart

Tags: gears, cassette

I am looking at purchasing a 9 speed 11-46 cassette but on inspection the bigger cogs are not equally apart from the smaller ones.  How would you go on with indexing (I use a thumb shifter 9 speed) if the gaps aren't equal as I'm guessing my shifter pulls and pushes the same amount of cable per click.

---

EG Cassette Range: 11-13-15-18-21-24-28-32-37-46T these arent equally spaced apart in particular the biggest ring is alot further away from 2nd ring 9 tooth difference than the others that are 2-4 tooth difference.

Comment: Be aware that Shimano cassettes may have thin (<1mm) spacers between the sprockets, at least those that come as single. They may easily come amiss, especially if the cassette isn't in its original packaging.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you're talking about the tooth difference, and not the horizontal spacing between cogs.  Most cassettes are "uneven" in this sense.  It does not affect indexed shifting, so long as the derailer can accommodate the max number of links difference and can "reach" as high as the largest cog.

Answer (score 2):

Once the cassette is mounted and the lockring is tight, the cogs should be equally spaced. To my knowledge, Shimano and SRAM cassettes have all had equal spacing between cogs.

A side note: Campagnolo is the sole exception to this. Their loose spacers are not equally thick. I think their rationale is something about improved shifting. In practice, for their 11s cassettes, you can't visually tell that the cog-cog spacing is uneven once installed anyway. Anyway, their shifters have a ratchet which controls how much cable is pulled with each shift. That's how their system indexes the gears. If you mounted a 10s or 9s Campagnolo cassette on a Shimano system of the same number of speeds, you might be able to adjust the gears to shift acceptably, although it would be a lot more prone to coming out of adjustment. At 11s and up, the differences in cog-cog spacing are so small that the cassettes are actually interchangeable.

Comment: Shimano Deore CS-M4100 10 Speed Cassette - 11-46T- Cassette Range: 11-13-15-18-21-24-28-32-37-46T these arent equally spaced apart in particular the biggest ring is alot further away from 2nd ring 9 tooth difference than the others that are 2-4 tooth difference.if you saw an image you would know what i mean.

Comment: @elpocketo I see. This raises the issue that Daniel mentioned in his answer. I'm talking about the lateral spacing between the cogs. You are talking about the number of teeth difference between each cog. That latter difference is irrelevant as long as your derailleur has adequate capacity.